# DeleteFields without receiving error message when no fields are deleted

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, fields-attributes, error-000735

The code below deletes fields I deem unnecessary (those not defined in 'keepFields') as I would like it to.

```
def EnvCompliance_Del(Workspace):
    env.workspace = Workspace
    Fields = arcpy.ListFields('aFeatureClass')
    keepFields = ['Field_A', 'Field_B', 'Field_C')
    in_table = 'aFeatureClass' + '.dbf'  
    drop_fields = [x.name for x in Fields if x.name not in keepFields]
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(in_table, drop_fields)

EnvCompliance_Del(r'C:database.gdb')
```

When there are no extra fields, however, I receive an error message that states:

> raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
>   ERROR 000735: Drop Field: Value is required Failed to execute
>   (DeleteField).

What can I add so that code prints some message stating something similar to "no unnecessary fields within 'aFeatureClass' exist" rather than the error message. My initial thought is an if-else statement, where the 'else' portion prints the message, but I am unable to successfully incorporate it.

Comment: Take a look at [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#errors-and-exceptions) section of the Python help, especially section [8.3 Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#errors-and-exceptions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip the drop fields if no drop fields are present:

```
...
drop_fields = [x.name for x in Fields if x.name not in keepFields]
if len(drop_fields) >0: arcpy.DeleteField_management(in_table, drop_fields)
else: print("No Extra Fields Found")
...
```

Comment: Empty lists in Python are treated as `False`, so the expression can be simplified to `if drop_fields: <code>`